# pyspark 2.3.2 : dataframe --> shift rows with 1, by a column --> on a column with dates

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Best

At this moment I'm experimenting with pyspark 2.3.2.
And I would like to shift a column based on a certain column (group by).

**Input:**

```
    id  timestamp                logintype  start_sessie    timestamp_prev
0   3   2016-02-09 09:36:57.217     INTERN  True            None
1   3   2016-02-09 09:51:40.899     INTERN  False           None
2   3   2016-02-10 10:11:22.131     INTERN  True            None
3   3   2016-02-10 10:17:16.345     INTERN  False           None
4   4   2017-08-10 10:18:12.412     INTERN  True            None
5   4   2017-08-10 10:21:11.788     INTERN  False           None
6   4   2017-08-11 14:17:33.119     INTERN  True            None
7   4   2017-08-11 14:11:51.173     INTERN  False           None
8   4   2017-08-16 11:43:16.609     INTERN  True            None
9   4   2017-08-16 11:13:35.421     INTERN  False           None
```

Lucky, since pyspark 2.3.x we can use pandas_udf.
Therefore I had this piece of code into my mind

**my code:**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType

@pandas_udf(data_shift_prep.schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def test(pdf):
    pdf["timestamp_prev"] = pdf['timestamp'].shift(1)
    return pdf

data_shift = data_shift_prep.groupby('id').apply(test)
```

with the following expected result:

**Expected result:**

```
    id  timestamp                logintype  start_sessie    timestamp_prev
0   3   2016-02-09 09:36:57.217     INTERN  True            None
1   3   2016-02-09 09:51:40.899     INTERN  False           2016-02-09 09:36:57.217
2   3   2016-02-10 10:11:22.131     INTERN  True            2016-02-09 09:51:40.899
3   3   2016-02-10 10:17:16.345     INTERN  False           2016-02-10 10:11:22.131
4   4   2017-08-10 10:18:12.412     INTERN  True            None
5   4   2017-08-10 10:21:11.788     INTERN  False           2017-08-10 10:18:12.412
6   4   2017-08-11 14:17:33.119     INTERN  True            2017-08-10 10:21:11.788
7   4   2017-08-11 14:11:51.173     INTERN  False           2017-08-11 14:17:33.119 
8   4   2017-08-16 11:43:16.609     INTERN  True            2017-08-11 14:11:51.173
9   4   2017-08-16 11:13:35.421     INTERN  False           2017-08-16 11:43:16.609
```

But unfortunately, I receive always an error.
`pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Error converting from Python objects to Int64: Got Python object of type Timestamp but can only handle these types: integer`

And i don't know how to handle it. 
First i thought, it was because of the ***NaT*** which are created by the shift function. But i'm not sure about it (I still have a same type of error after replacing the NaT by an **None** value)

Does someone has some more experience with this? (and can you solve this type error)

kind regards

-- Add extra : **schema** --

```
StructType(List(StructField(id,IntegerType,true),
                StructField(timestamp,TimestampType,true),
                StructField(logintype,StringType,true),
                StructField(start_sessie,BooleanType,true),
                StructField(timestamp_prev,TimestampType,true)))
```

Comment: Could you add `data_shift_prep` schema?

Comment: Why can't you use `lag` (or `lead`)? It will be something like `df.withColumn("timestamp_prev", lag("timestamp").over(Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("timestamp")))`

Comment: @user10465355 - i've added the schema

Comment: @pault - can be a sollution, but its more about testing the pandas functionallity ... how it returns data back etc